# EPERM -4048, operation not permitted, unlink

Tags: javascript, node.js, ionic-framework, npm

Whenever I try to install anything with npm install, I get the following error (usually referencing a different path). I've tried npm cache clean but that gets a similar error. I tried restarting the PC and checked for processes that may be using npm. Followed several other answers and none of the ones I've tried have been successful.

The attached screenshot was taken just after uninstalling node, restarting my computer, removing everything about npm from AppData and Program Files etc. and then creating a brand new project to test in. The project and the directory were created in command line.

Any help would be truly appreciated. Thanks!

[SCREENSHOT](https://i.stack.imgur.com/p1vtM.png)

Comment: you need to run the command as administrator.
i.e right click on command prompt -> Run As Administrator

Comment: I've been doing that every single time.

Comment: try `npm cache clean --force` and then do the installation again

Comment: Try to install nvm-windows and install your node via that, makes these problems mostly go away.

Comment: That didn't work either

Answer (score -1):

You are trying to install the npm using the command

```
npm install -g cordova ionic
```

But it is supposed to be like

```
npm install ionic cordova -g
        or
npm install -g ionic cordova
```

For more info check the below link
 [Error: EPERM: operation not permitted](https://forum.ionicframework.com/t/error-eperm-operation-not-permitted/92788)

Comment: that makes no difference.

Comment: That was just an example. I'm getting the same error code for literally every "npm install ___" I try.